# Migrating Primary Key column type from Integer to BigInt in Derby

Tags: java, sql, database-design, derby, database-migration

I've developed a software that is in production now & used by 5 clients.
I am using Derby database.

But, Now, I realized that I should've designed one table Primary Key Column with `BigInt` Datatype instead of `Integer` type.

So how can I alter the table safely, in the case when this table has relationship with other tables also through this Primary Key Column?

And, If I would like to change type of all table Primary Key Columns from `Integer` to `BigInt`, will there be any effect on performance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD COLUMN NEW_COLUMN BIGINT;  
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET NEW_COLUMN=MY_COLUMN;  
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP COLUMN MY_COLUMN;  
RENAME COLUMN MY_TABLE.NEW_COLUMN TO MY_COLUMN;
```

Discussed [here](http://codeblow.com/questions/how-you-can-alter-a-column-datatype-for-derby-database/)